# How to change a URL in Jenkins sidebar menu

Tags: jenkins

I duplicated VM of Jenkins and changed the URL from jenkins-dev to jenkins-test. All other menu buttons are linked to jenkins-test properly but only one menu (New View) from side bar keeps connecting to jenkins-dev.

I was trying to find main html page or index file of Jenkins to modify the url from jenkins-dev to jenkins-test but I can't find it where it is. Unfortunately I'm not good at web programming..

It's showing 
a class="task-link" href="https://jenkins-dev.xxx.xxx/newView"

but other correct menus are showing 
a class="task-link" href="/credentials"

Answer (score 1):

I just found that 'Jenkins Location' in [Jenkins-Configure System] was set with 'jenkins-dev' URL.

After modifying the URL to 'jenkins-test.xxx.xxx', New View menu was also fixed not to direct to 'jenkins-dev.xxx.xxx'.

I will keep my question for someone who has the same issue like me! XD

Cheers!

Comment: great news that you found the solution. Please mark your own answer as the solution when the site lets you do that in a few days.